# Updating mysql database using html form works for say grocerystore1 but not for grocerystore2

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an html form which updates fields like usp, description, area etc of grocery stores. When i choose any grocery store to update it, the details that are already there in the database are fetched to the text area of the html form so that I can see what is there already  before I can update it.

Let me give an example:

suppose these are the details already in the database for the two grocery stores.

GROCERY STORE1:

```
usp: fresh
description:very good store
area: boston
```

GROCERY STORE2:

```
usp:fresh products, nice store look, very good service, customer friendly, bla bla bla...
description: located in one of the poshest places of the city this store is unique bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ..............
area: boston
```

Now when i used the html form to update these fields, it updates perfectly fine for GROCERY STORE1. But for GROCERY STORE2  it doesnt update. The reason I found out was that there is already too much text in the fields of GROCERY STORE2 . Then I went to my database and edited the details for GROCERY STORE2 to a minimum, for example usp: good, description:nice, area,boston. Now when I use the html form to update it , it works fine. So whenever there is too much text already, this html form doesnt seem to work. How can I solve this. Thanks in advance

PHP code is

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['usp'])) 
{
//If not isset -> set with dumy value 
$_POST['usp'] = ""; 
}

if (!isset($_POST['area_served'])) 
{
//If not isset -> set with dumy value 
$_POST['area_served'] = ""; 
}

if (!isset($_POST['description'])) 
{
//If not isset -> set with dumy value 
$_POST['description'] = ""; 
}




if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    //If not isset -> set with dumy value 
    $_POST['submit'] = ""; 
}

$usp = $_POST['usp'];
$area_served = $_POST['area_served'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if($submit)
{
$insert=mysql_query("UPDATE stores SET usp='$usp',area_served='$area_served',description='$description', WHERE store_id=$storeid");
header("Location:updateinfo.php?city_id=$cityid&store_id=$storeid");
}
?>
```

HTML code is

```
    <form name="myForm" action="" method="POST" action="condatabase.php" >
    <div>
    <label for="myname">USP*:</label>
    <textarea name="usp" id="box1" rows="5" cols="5"><?PHP echo $record12['usp']?>    
    </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="area_served">Areas served*:</label>
    <textarea name="area_served" id="box1" rows="5" cols="5"><?PHP echo    
    $record12['area_served']?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div> 
    <label for="email">description*:</label>
    <textarea name="description" id="box1" rows="5" cols="5"><?PHP echo    
    $record12['description']?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="thesubmit">
    <button class="button" input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment"   
    />Submit</button>
    </div> <br>
    <div id="thesubmit">
    <button class="button" input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" />Reset</button></div> 
    </form>
```

Comment: The issue is not in your form, but the use of mysql_query: 1. Escape the input 2. do not use mysql_query

Comment: Can you please let me know what can I use instead of mysql_query. And one more thing I wanted to ask was that , why does it work for one store and not for the other. Is it that it gets timed out before the long text is submitted

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are defining the `$storeid` variable ? It can be this.

Also, you have an extra comma in your query just before the `WHERE`. So try

```
$insert=mysql_query("UPDATE stores SET usp='$usp',area_served='$area_served',description='$description' WHERE store_id=$storeid");
```

instead of

```
$insert=mysql_query("UPDATE stores SET usp='$usp',area_served='$area_served',description='$description', WHERE store_id=$storeid");
```

Comment: Thanks ... but the store id i get it using $GET which then passes it on to this $storeid. The queries are working all fine .... But as I had said if the text is less only then it works, if text entered in the form is more it doesnt work.

Answer (score -1):

Also be sure that you escape special chars in you text

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php